# How do i concatenate array elements based on af specific element in array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, concatenation

So i have an array that looks kinda like this:

```
["John", "Doe", "123456789", "Abbey", "Road", "201", "2000", "Copenhagen"]
```

First Name,
Sirname,
phone number,
first name of the road,
second name of the road,
house number,
postal code,
and town.

The goal is that i have to get the whole address (first road name, second road name and house number) into one array element.

But the number of elements that relates to the address varies.

It could be Abbey Road 201, Melon 1 or Melon Strawberry Lemon Apple 3. the phone number and postal code will always be in the same spot

What i would like to figure out is how to concatenate the address elements no matter how many elements the address has.

Kinda like this:

```
["John", "Doe", "123456789", "Abbey Road 201", "2000", "Copenhagen"]
```

Comment: your question isn't clear, but it sounds like you may be trying to get everything joined up into a single string? In which case, [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) is what you're after.

Comment: are there multiple inputs? like address1 address2 city state... etc? Why is this in an array if you have inputs

Comment: It's an array strings created from a docx document that gets passed in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example, using `splice`:

```js
const arr = ["John", "Doe", "123456789", "Abbey", "Road", "201", "2000", "Copenhagen"];

const indexOfFirstRoadName = 3;
const indexOfPostalCode = 6;
const deleteCount = indexOfPostalCode - indexOfFirstRoadName;
const address = arr.slice(indexOfFirstRoadName, indexOfPostalCode).join(' ');

arr.splice(indexOfFirstRoadName, deleteCount, address);
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That got me a really long way! Now i just need to get the index of the postalcode dynamically :) Bur really, thank you

Answer (score 0):

For dynamically getting the index of the postal code i figured ths out:

```
function getPostalIndex(array) {
let postal;for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] === "Danmark" || array[i] === "Sverige") {
        postal = i - 2;
    }
}
return postal;
```

}